# How can I remove curly brackets as well as the text inside of it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
hello_world{552}.txt
{hix89}abcdefg{47181x00}.exe
```

How can I output these strings to look like `"hello_world.txt,abcdefg.exe"`
with double quotation and comma without spacing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex and find solution:

```
output=[]
test=['hello_world{552}.txt','ggfj{hix89}abcdefg{47181x00}.exe']
for x in test:
    out = re.sub('{\w*}','',x)
    output.append(out)
print(output)
final_o = ",".join(output)
print(str(final_o))
```

Output:

```
hello_world.txt,ggfjabcdefg.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your problem correctly, you need to get rid of all brackets and connect two strings together, plus surround with double quotes.

```
ls = ['hello_world{552}.txt', '{hix89}abcdefg{47181x00}.exe']

def delete_content_of_brackets(ls):
    result = ""
    bracket_is_open = False
    for element in ls:
        for character in element:
            if character == "}":
                bracket_is_open = False
            elif character == "{" or bracket_is_open:
                bracket_is_open = True
            else:
                result += character
        result += ","
    
    return "\"" + result[:-1]+"\""
```